# User input to break while loop to return to the main

Tags: c, codeblocks

So, I need to break the loop with the user input if it was C, but it does not break the loop and return to the main.

It sticks to the same loop.

```
void createFile(void)
{
    FILE *NewFile;
    char *file_name = malloc(sizeof(*file_name));
    printf("\nEnter a name of the file you want to create:\n");
    scanf("%s",file_name);

    while(access(file_name, 0) != -1)//in case the file exists
        {
        printf("\n%s file already exists\nplease re_enter your file name or C to go back to the main menu.\n\n", file_name);
        scanf("%s", file_name);
        if ( file_name == 'C')
        {
            return;// returning to the main menu
        }
        }
    if(access(file_name, 0) == -1)//if it does not exist
    {
        NewFile = fopen(file_name,"w+");
        fclose(NewFile);
        printf("\nFile has been created successfully! :D\n\nPlease enter R to return to the main menu ");
        scanf("%s",file_name);
        if (file_name == 'R')
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    remove("C"); // just in case unwanted C file is created.
    remove("R");
}
```

Comment: Is this a c# question?

Comment: No, sorry I mistakenly put c# . It is c programming.

Comment: Replace your while with an if statement. Then add a `while (true)` at the beginning of this method, and replace your first `return` with `continue`

Comment: It is still looping unfortunately. The problem here it doesn't recognize the input 'C' as the returning input.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler give you a warning or two with that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_name` is a pointer to a character. (It's actually a pointer to the first character of a NUL-terminated sequence of characters, but it is still a pointer to a character.) That's evident from the declaration:

```
char *file_name;
```

On the other hand, `'C'` is an integer. Most likely, it is the integer 67, which is the ascii code for the letter C.

So you are comparing a pointer -- that is, an address -- with an integer.

In C that's actually legal, but it is only meaningful if the integer you are comparing the pointer with is 0. So your compiler should warn you about this.

The end result is that the comparison `file_name == 'C'` is evaluating to 0 (false).

What you intended to do was to compare the string pointed to by `file_name` with the string literal `"C"`, which you would do as follows:

```
if (strcmp(file_name, "C") == 0))
```

`strcmp` is a standard library function which compares two character strings (given pointers to their respective initial characters) and returns a negative integer if the first one comes first (alphabetically), a positive integer if the second one comes first, and 0 if the two strings are equal.

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration sir @rici, as you can see, i am still working my way through c programming actually. I was thinking of the ascii code problem, but strcmp didn't come to my mind though.